# Is indentation of #if & #endif directives an important readability convention?

Tags: c#

I'm sharing C# code with a fellow programmer who is more use to writing C++. He uses `#if` and `#endif` directives (which I do not tend to use) and when they occur they have no indentation, for example

```
        private void dumpToDisplay()
        {
#if false
            ushort[] ScanStatus = new ushort[6];
            for (int ch = 0; ch < 6; ch++)
                ScanStatus[ch] = mySteppers.GetStatus(ch);

            return;
#endif
            string dumpString = stepDump();

            Debug.Print(dumpString);
        }
```

It is interesting that the code sample in [the `#if` C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) adopts the same convention and has no indentation for the `#if` and `#endif` directives. Is this important? It certainly makes them stand out, but is that good?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is indentation of #if & #endif directives an important readability convention?

I think you mean outdentation (i.e. the `#if` is at the start of the line).

I'd say 'yes' because:

- It's conventional
- Unlike `if` statements, `#if ... #endif` statements don't use braces (`{` and `}`)
- The contents of (i.e. lines between) a `#if ... #endif` don't have an extra indent (as they would inside an `if { ... }` statement)

It's also/more important for readability to have a language-aware IDE which:

- Knows what preprocessor symbols are defined/redefined
- Therefore knows whether each `#if` is true or false
- And colorizes the text accordingly (e.g. grey for disabled text)

---

The Visual Studio IDE automatically moves `#if` statements to the left-most column. Any formatting which the IDE does automatically is, I assume, the best way to do it (if only because otherwise you're fighting with the IDE reformatting your code).

Answer (score 14):

I think it makes sense this way, because the `#if` directives are pretty much outside of the normal syntax. For example, you can write something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (CheckConditionDebug())
    {
        DoADebug();
#else
    if (CheckCondition())
    {
        DoA();
#endif
        DoB();
    }
```

This is valid code in both states (`DEBUG` defined or not), but there is no good way to indent the directives.

Note: I'm not saying that this is a good use of `#if`, just that it is a possible use and that it makes sense to take this into account.